# n-dimensional Gaussian integral with absolute values

Tags: integration, physics, matrix-calculus, gaussian-integral, quantum-field-theory

Given two matrix $A$ and $D$ and a column vector $x$, what is the value of the following integral?

$\int d^nx \; \; e^{x^T A x + \mid x \mid^T D \mid x \mid + B x}$

where $\mid x \mid_i = \mid x_i \mid$

And what are the requirements on $A$ and $D$ to have convergence ?

Thank you!

edit: for simplicity it is possible to assume that $A$ and $D$ are both symmetrical and diagonalizeble by the same orthogonal matrix $M$

Comment: Is $|x|$ supposed to be a vector that has each element of $x$ with its absolute value taken?  Usually it would be the length of $x$ and a scalar.

Comment: yes $\mid x \mid_i = \mid x_i \mid$ , added in the question too

Comment: Hint: go to the diagonal representation: how has the row vector B transformed? Try with just two dimensional vectors first.  This is clearly a homework problem.

Comment: That is exactly what I struggle to understand, how $B$ get transformed by $M$ (given that the classical transformation that would give $B^T A^{-1} B$ do not work)

Comment: Still not able to figure it how

Comment: Out of curiosity, did this integral arise in some application?

Comment: Yes it does actually